# JavaScript GetFullYear Function Bug

Tags: javascript, datetime

One small defect is that if the client side system date is old, then the site also displays it likewise. For example your copyrights are from year 2000 till 2019. If someone has date of year 2017, then the footer displays copyrights from 2000 till 2017. Is there a way to resolve it? Instead of getting date from client, get a universal year from google

## Experiment

I changed my window's date from 2019 to 2017, when I refreshed the website it showed me 2017 in the footer instead of the real world date.

Comment: I'm surprised you can still connect to the internet by not having a current date and time. Most internet connection devices require the current date, within a few seconds. If people are somehow accessing your site with an incorrect date, there's more going on than a "bad" JavaScript method.

Comment: send it from your web server.

Comment: Thats why haven't globalized my site yet, this problem just got revealed during I was working on local host.

Comment: @Daniel A. White you mean php?

Comment: how is javascript to know what the correct date is?

Comment: @ZMKhan that is one option. it depends on what you know and what you are doing.

Comment: @DanielA.White This experiment also takes place if the system date is changed [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_getfullyear), give it a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196887/discussion-between-daniel-a-white-and-zmkhan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the time using the Date() method directly - which retrieves the time from the users browser/operating system - you could query a web service which acts as a time server.

https://worldtimeapi.org/ is a good candidate.

A simple **XmlHttpRequest** can be made to:

```
https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Etc/UTC
```

to get a JSON response like:

```
week_number 30
utc_offset  "+00:00"
utc_datetime    "2019-07-23T19:45:27.238014+00:00"
unixtime    1563911127
timezone    "Etc/UTC"
raw_offset  0
dst_until   null
dst_offset  0
dst_from    null
dst false
day_of_year 204
day_of_week 2
datetime    "2019-07-23T19:45:27.238014+00:00"
client_ip   "12.34.56.78"
abbreviation    "UTC"
```

If you feed the **utc_dateTime** to the constructor of Javascript's Date() object you can get the correct year.

Here's an example:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Etc/UTC");
xhr.onload = function() {
  var arr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  var date = new Date(arr.utc_datetime);
  console.log(date.getFullYear());
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Excellent Solution

Comment: Glad I could help ZMKhan!